# html, body getting applied with last value in CSS file

Tags: css

I have below CSS code in my CSS class.

```
.ie8 html, body {
padding-left: 140px;
}

html, body {
padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Here `html,body` is the last entry. So, for ie8, `html, body` is getting applied.

Now, if I swap them, then `.ie8 html, body` will be the last entry. So, for Chrome and FF, .ie8 attributes are getting applied.

CSS file is referred externally from web server.

How to solve this?

Comment: What element are you wrapping `html` with? The `html` should be the root element; so the selector `.ie8 html` shouldn't be able to match any elements or be applied at all. References: [`<html>` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/html), [`html` (W3.org)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/html.html#html).

Comment: should there be a `.ie8` before `body` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Musa says, `.ie8 html, body` will apply to two distinct things:

- a `html` element that is under class `ie8` element (which probably does not exist, since `html` should be the top element)
- and every `body` element (`ie8` class selector does apply here).

Thus, you have two rules handling `body`, and the second one overwrites the first. If you switch them around, the effect changes. You probably want `html.ie8 body`, or `.ie8 body` (for just `body` element), or `html.ie8, html.ie8 body`, or `.ie8, .ie8 body` (for both `html` and `body` elements).